# How to know if I need to reverse the thresholding TYPE after findContour

Tags: python, opencv, contour, image-thresholding

I'm working with OpenCV on hand detection. But I'm struggling when trying to contours of the threshed image. `findContour` will always try to find white area as contour.

So basically it works in most cases but sometimes my threshed image looks like this :

`_, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)`
[image: Base]
[image]

So to make it works I just need to change the threshold type `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`.

`_, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)`

[image: Reverse]
[image: DrawContour]

And it works well.

**My question is how can I determine when the threshold need to be reversed ? Does I Need to always found contours on both threshed images, and compare the result (I this case How ?) ? or there is a way to allays knows if contours are not totally missed.**

**EDIT** : There is a way to be 100% sure contour looks like a hand ?

**EDIT 2** : So I forgot to mention that I'm trying to detect fingertips and defects using this [method](https://medium.com/@muehler.v/simple-hand-gesture-recognition-using-opencv-and-javascript-eb3d6ced28a0#2a3a) so I need defects, which with the first threshed image I can't find them, because it reversed. See blue point on the First contour [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8g7q.png).

Thanks.

Comment: findContours will work the same on inversed binary image, so if you just need the contour, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Ok my bad i forgot some informations I will edit question. Just here I need to detect defects points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a utility method to detect the most dominant color along the border and then decide the logic, as if you want to invert the image or not, so the flow may look like:

1. Use OSTU binarization method.
2. Pass the thresholded image to utility method `get_most_dominant_border_color` and get the dominant color.
3. If the border color is `WHITE`, then you should invert the image using `cv2.bitwise_not`, else keep it that way only.

The `get_most_dominant_border_color` could be defined as:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_most_dominant_border_color(img):
    # Get the top row
    row_1 = img[0, :]
    # Get the left-most column
    col_1 = img[:, 0]
    # Get the bottom row
    row_2 = img[-1, :]
    # Get the right-most column
    col_2 = img[:, -1]

    combined_li = row_1.tolist() + row_2.tolist() + col_1.tolist() + col_2.tolist()

    color_counter = Counter(combined_li)

    return max(color_counter.keys(), key=lambda x:color_counter.values())
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the algorithme, but I got an `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'` exception on this line : `return max(color_counter.keys(), key=lambda x:color_counter.values())`. Could you explain more what it does ? Mostly the `key: lambda part` ?

Comment: Which Python version are you using ?

Comment: python3.7.3, i figured out what is the problem, I'm currently trying to resolve it. When I print `color_counter.keys()` it's return `dict_keys([255, 0])` instead of `[255, 0]`.

Comment: So to avoid this error I convert the keys to list and it works. KEYS : `colors_keys = list(color_counter.keys())` -- VALUES : `colors_values = list(color_counter.values())` -- MAX : `dominant_color = max(colors_keys, key=lambda x:colors_values)`